# Decomposition into eigenfunctions which eigenvalues are the order of Bessel functions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, bessel-functions

In a physics problem I need to solve an equation which involves eigenvalues of the differential operator $L$ applied to a function $f:x\mapsto f(x), x\in \mathbb{R}^+$.
$L$ is given by
\begin{equation}
 L = x^2 {d\over dx} + x{d\over dx} + x^2. \label{a}
\end{equation}
You can see that the eigen-problem $L[\tilde{f}_\nu] = \nu^2 \tilde{f}_\nu$ is simply the Bessel equation which has solutions given by Bessel functions of order $\nu$.

I want to decompose the general solution $f$ into the "modes" $f_\nu$ using the scalar product
$$ \left<f,g\right> = \int_0^{+\infty} {dx\over x} f(x)\overline{g(x)}$$
This is the same idea as usual Fourier decomposition of the operator ${d^2\over dx^2} = -k^2$. A very helpful aspect of the Fourier basis $e^{ikx}$ is that it is orthogonal as
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} dx e^{i(k-q)x} = \delta(k-q).$$

However, the Bessel functions are not strictly orthogonal since it gives the cardinal sine
$$\left<J_\alpha,J_\beta\right>= \int_0^{+\infty} {dx\over x}J_\alpha(x)J_\beta(x) = {\sin_c({\pi\over 2 }(\alpha-\beta))\over \alpha+\beta}$$
for $\text{Re}(\alpha+\beta) > 0$.
Does anyone know if

- there is a way to obtain an orthogonal basis, for example by changing the definition of the scalar product (by adding boundary terms?)
- a decomposition into a sum of modes is still possible with a non-orthogonal basis?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your integral concerning the Fourier transform is not correct.

Comment: OK, my bad. I was thinking of the Dirac distribution, but the integral itself oscillates. I correct this.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts But what do you think of this? https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/LinAlg/deltaexp.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a a very rigorous approach to the Fourier transform. This type of inversion integral is what you want to consider $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-r}^{r}e^{ixs}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-isx}dx\right)ds$. Then the part of the integrand multiplying $f$ looks like a Dirac delta, after you exchange orders of integration. And that type of technique works for the Bessel expansions, too. The Bessel functions are messier, and you don't have the same type of translational invariance that you do for the ordinary Fourier case.

Comment: By the way, the correct inner product for the Bessel Functions is multiplication by 'x' instead of division by 'x'. That would definitely affect the integrals that you want to evaluate. So, if you want to continue with your approach, replace $1/x$ with $x$ instead, and see if that gives you what you want.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts The scalar product with 1/x corresponds to the Sturm-Liouville problem $L[f] = \nu^2 f$. Here $\nu$ is the Bessel's order. You probably have in mind the more common one with Bessels when the eigenvalue is not $\nu$ but something like $k$ for $J_\nu(kx)$. In this case the weight function is the $x$ you mention.